# How to delete all git repositories in a certain folder?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I'm looking for an option to delete ALL `.git` folders on my local folder on the PC, so it won't be that massive.

I have tried to use [`rimraf` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf), but there are no filter options in there,

Any ideas?

Comment: `find -name .git -prune -exec rm -rf {} +`

Answer (score 1):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/facelordgists/80e868ff5e315878ecd6) offers the more complete command, to execute in a bash session, even on Windows:

```
find . \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name ".gitmodules" -o -name ".gitattributes" \) -prune -exec rm -rf -- {} +
```

So it does not use `npm`, but rather a native Git bash session.